# Two inputs on self loop, deterministic or non-deterministic state machine?

Tags: state, finite-automata, deterministic, non-deterministic, automaton

Wikipedia states that a Deterministic State Automation "produces a unique computation (or run) of the automaton for each input string".

I always understood this as there being only 1 possible path to compute any unique string. In which case, the following is a DSM.

But now i'm overthinking this and interpreting the description as each input string having a single possible path, and that path is unique from all other input strings. In which case, the following isn't a DSM as '11' and '12' follow the same paths.

So my question is, is the following a DSM or NDSM?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its still deterministic, there is only one possible path for each input from each state. 1, and 2 can only go back to itself, for it to be non deterministic, the input should have multiple possible paths. Such as if input 1 had two possible states branching from one specific state.

In short, if there are not branching paths for a specific input, and no [ε-edges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton_with_%CE%B5-moves) in the graph, it should be deterministic. i.e. no branching paths, we can determine for sure where it goes. The one you drew above we can always determine the path for a specific input.

Answer (score 0):

It is surely a Deterministic Finite Automata as it has unique path for every move defined for any of the state.

If we input 1 to this automata, there is only one **unique** move defined for 1 from initial to the final state. After reaching final state, we don't care if the input is 1 or 2. Had there been multiple moves defined for any state, it would be Non-deterministic Finite Automata.